# Xamarin Forms - Hidden field that hold Unique id on page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to store id in back of the page. in web application we are using Hiddenfield for this. but i am not getting any way in xamarin forms. how do i hold unique id on page?

Is there any way to to hide any label or any text field so that i can store ID in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you want to here, but why don't you just add a **Label** and set its `IsVisible` property to `false`? It'll act like a HiddenField.

Or you can just set the value `Tag` property of any of your other fields with the Unique ID.

Another way is why not use [MVVM Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)? In order for you to easily work with data, which I would recommend but will take you alot of time to set up.

But I guess what you're looking for is a quick fix, The first two would suffice.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Currently i use Label for this. and it works Thank u

Answer (score 1):

As @mindofai says, if you use MVVM then your Id can just be a field or property of the PageModel associated with the Forms page. You don't need hidden UI elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find `Tag` property for some reasons, you can still use `ClassId` for bindable field or `StyleId` for plain text.